# Summarise en R, Conservando Variable Categórica

Tags: base-de-datos, r, r-dplyr

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos transaccional que contiene las compras realizadas por los clientes en dos tiendas distintas.

La base tiene el siguiente formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito realizar es para cada cliente (Email) determinar la fecha minima (Primera Compra), cual fue el producto mas caro que se compro en esa fecha (Una misma transacción puede tener mas de una fila con distinto producto), de igual forma determinar la fecha máxima de compra (Última Compra) y el producto que se adquirió para cada una de las dos tiendas (Última Columna).

Para eso estoy ocupando el siguiente código:

```
CLIENTE_TIPO <- FISICO3%>%

            group_by(EMAIL, `Sub Categoría`)%>%

            summarise(Fechamin = min(CreatedAt),
                      LINEA_1 = LINEAFIN[which.max(ITEM_PRECIO)],
                      Fechamax = max(CreatedAt), 
                      LINEA_LAST =  LINEAFIN[which.max(ITEM_PRECIO)],
                      Nombre = NOMBRES[which.max(ITEM_PRECIO)],
                      Diff = Fechamax - Fechamin)%>%

          mutate(Dosmas = ifelse(Fechamin == Fechamax, "1 Compra", "2 + Compras"),
                 EMAIL = str_to_lower(EMAIL))%>%

          filter(nchar(EMAIL) > 5)
```

El problema que tengo es que al seleccionar el producto (LINEAFIN)  mas caro de la primera y ultima compra, me esta seleccionando el producto mas caro de todas las fecha y no de la fecha mínimo ni máxima, por lo cual es ambos casos me queda el mismo producto, de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería si me pudieran ayudar a resolver este problema, ya intente agrando la fecha al group_by, pero hace lo mismo.

Gracias de antemano !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es difícil reproducir el problema sin la base de datos, pero según entendí, quieres el producto mas caro, pero estos asociados a las fechas mínimas y máximas,
por lo que veo en esta parte del codigo:

```
LINEA_1 = LINEAFIN[which.max(ITEM_PRECIO)],
LINEA_LAST =  LINEAFIN[which.max(ITEM_PRECIO)]
```

No estas condicionando en ninguna parte que el precio del producto este asociado a fechas mínimas ni máximas, por lo que es natural que te retorne el producto mas caro de todas las fechas, para solucionar esto, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
summarise(
  Fechamin = min(CreatedAt),
  LINEA_1 = LINEAFIN[ITEM_PRECIO == max(ITEM_PRECIO[CreatedAt == min(CreatedAt)])],
  Fechamax = max(CreatedAt),
  LINEA_LAST = LINEAFIN[ITEM_PRECIO == max(ITEM_PRECIO[CreatedAt == max(CreatedAt)])]
  Nombre = NOMBRES[which.max(ITEM_PRECIO)],
  Diff = Fechamax - Fechamin
)
```

Es decir, buscar el precio máximo asociado a la mayor y menor fecha y de este encontrar el producto asociado

Comment: Muchas gracias! Eso era lo que me estaba faltando!